# ocaml c interop passing struct

Tags: c, ocaml, interop

I hit weird case when trying to call c from ocaml.
This is the c side of things:

```
typedef struct {
  TSNode node;
} AstNode;

CAMLprim value caml_ts_document_root_node(value document) {
  CAMLparam1(document);
  TSNode root_node = ts_document_root_node(document);
  AstNode elNode;
  elNode.node = root_node;
  CAMLreturn(&elNode);
}

CAMLprim value caml_ts_node_string(value node) {
  CAMLparam1(node)
  CAMLlocal1(mls);

  AstNode* n = (AstNode*) node;

  char *s = ts_node_string(n->node);
  mls = caml_copy_string(s);
  CAMLreturn(mls);
}
```

On the ocaml side

```
type ts_point
type ts_document

external ts_node_string : ts_node -> string = "caml_ts_node_string"
external ts_document_root_node : ts_document -> ts_node = "caml_ts_document_root_node"
```

If you see the code, I'm wrapping in `caml_ts_document_root_node` the `TSNode root_node = ts_document_root_node(document);` in an extra defined struct `AstNode`.

When I write the following implementation however:

```
CAMLprim value caml_ts_document_root_node(value document) {
  CAMLparam1(document);
  TSNode root_node = ts_document_root_node(document);

  CAMLreturn(&root_node);
```

}

My code segfaults when calling `caml_ts_node_string` on the returned node by `caml_ts_document_root_node`.

Does anyone have any hints on why the segfault appears when I don't wrap a `TSNode` in an extra struct when interoping from ocaml?

Comment: You should take a look at [ctypes](https://github.com/ocamllabs/ocaml-ctypes), it's way more convenient

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's definitely not the right usage of the foreign interface! You can't just take a value and cast it to OCaml value. OCaml values are specially encoded, even integers, and have a different representation than C values.

If you want to encode a C value as an OCaml value, you shall use [custom values](https://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/intfc.html#sec459).

First of all, you need to implement the interface of a custom value, fortunately, you can rely on defaults for that:

```
static struct custom_operations ast_ops = {
        "ast_node",
        custom_finalize_default
        custom_compare_default,
        custom_hash_default,
        custom_serialize_default,
        custom_deserialize_default,
        custom_compare_ext_default
};
```

Next, you need to learn how to allocate custom blocks. For example, the following call will allocate the new AstNode in the OCaml heap:

```
    res = caml_alloc_custom(&ast_ops, sizeof(AstNode), 0, 1);
```

To access the value itself, you need to use the `Data_custom_val` macro, e.g.,

```
   if (res) {
      AstNode *node = Data_custom_val(res);
      TsNode *tsnode = res->node;
   }
```

The complete example of a correct (I hope) implementation of your first function is below:

```
CAMLprim value caml_ts_document_root_node(value document) {
  CAMLparam1(document);
  CAMLlocal1(res);
  res = caml_alloc_custom(&ast_ops, sizeof(AstNodes), 0, 1);
  if (res) {
    AstNode *ast = (AstNode *)Data_custom_val(res);
    ast->node = ts_document_root_node(document);
  } 
  CAMLreturn(res);
}
```

As you may see, this is not trivial and rather low-level. Though nothing really magical, especially after you've read the corresponding parts of the [OCaml documentation](https://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/intfc.html). However, it is much easier [to use the CTypes library](https://realworldocaml.org/v1/en/html/foreign-function-interface.html), that hides most of those complexities and allows you to call C function directly from OCaml

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be unrelated to the ocaml interop part; you are returning the address of a local variable in this function:

```
CAMLprim value caml_ts_document_root_node(value document) {
  // ...
  AstNode elNode;
  // ...
  CAMLreturn(&elNode);
}
```

When it returns, the (stack) memory it refers to is invalid (in the sense that it will be reused at the next function call).

Comment: Thanks, I had a feeling it had something to do with the c part. I'm very new to c in general. How do I pass the `TSNode root_node` to the ocaml side?